# Delete Data in Data Extension if the checkbox in CloudPage is empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I create a cloudpage with some checkboxes that reference a some Data Extension. Example image attached.

My attempted was use DeleteData in Ampscript with the syntax below:

Where Bike is my checkbox:

```
IF NOT EMPTY(@Bike) THEN
InsertData('Bike_DE','FirstName',@firstname,'LastName',@lastname,'Email',@email,'Telefone',@telefone,'CPF',@cpf)
ENDIF

IF EMPTY(@Bike) THEN
DeleteData('Bike_DE','FirstName',@firstname,'LastName',@lastname,'Email',@email,'Telefone',@telefone,'CPF',@cpf)
ENDIF
```

The fields in syntax like 'firstname' and etc. I want to delete if the checkbox was not checked.

I hope that my explanation that good. If anyone know how to help me, thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RequestParameter()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) AMPScript function to listen for sent values.
Assuming each [CheckBox](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp) is separate (different "Name" values), you can listen for each CheckBox value and process accordingly.
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Bike" value="1"> I have a bike
<input type="checkbox" name="Car" value="1"> I have a car
```

AMPScript:

```
IF EMPTY(RequestParameter('Bike')) THEN
//Do Delete Function
ELSE
//Do UpsertData Function
ENDIF

IF EMPTY(RequestParameter('Car')) THEN
//Do Delete Function
ELSE
//Do UpsertData Function
ENDIF
```

[UpsertData()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm) will Insert or Update depending on existing records in the data extension. This way you can update the "subscribeDate" to the last time they submitted their preferences.
If you don't want to Upsert, you could use a [RowCount()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/rowcount.htm) check on the target preference DE to see if a row already exists, then Update or Insert accordingly.

Note that when using CheckBoxes - unchecked values are NOT submitted in the Post Payload. 
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: Hi @CameronRobert. So thanks for the help, the code it's working fine. I did what you writed, but now i have another issue. If the record already exists in Data Extension and the Submit Button is clicked appears a error and the data does not insert.

Example: the user in first moment is  subscribed in Bike_DE, in secondo moment the user entry in DE and is marked the Bike_De and the Car_De, the erros appears and the records not inserted.

I tried to use UpdateData, but the record does not inserted.

Comment: Hey Joao, you can try use the UpsertData() function: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm I have updated my response to include this information

Comment: Thanks, @Cameron. The code works! If you can, you know a way to 'prepopulate' the checkbox if the email already in the DE. I know the fields with the RequestParameter